# Converted swift header is missing property

Tags: objective-c, swift

I'm using a framework, installed via cocoapods and discovered this weird behaviour in a header file.

This is how the swift (converted) file looks like:

```
/**
 *  The title of the note.
 */
public var title: String!

/**
 *  The content of the note.
 */
```

It's missing the content property. If I open "Navigate -> Jump to original source" I see that this property though does exist in the original objective-c header:

```
/**
 *  The title of the note.
 */
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString * title;

/**
 *  The content of the note.
 */
@property (nonatomic, strong) ENNoteContent * content;
```

Any ideas how this can happen?

Comment: Is Swift able to figure out what an `ENNoteContent` is?

Comment: Yes, I can compile something like `let content = ENNoteContent(string: "test")`